Robinhood crypto api cancelling limit order error
In the below code block are the basic functions that Robinhood provides to interact with their crypto api. I've been able to use most of these functions successfully, such as the 'get_orders', 'place_order' and 'get_trading_pair' functions.
class CryptoAPITrading:
    def __init__(self):
        self.api_key = API_KEY
        private_bytes = base64.b64decode(BASE64_PRIVATE_KEY)
        # Note that the cryptography library used here only accepts a 32 byte ed25519 private key
        self.private_key = ed25519.Ed25519PrivateKey.from_private_bytes(private_bytes[:32])
        self.base_url = "https://trading.robinhood.com"

    @staticmethod
    def _get_current_timestamp() -> int:
        return int(datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.timezone.utc).timestamp())

    @staticmethod
    def get_query_params(key: str, *args: Optional[str]) -> str:
        if not args:
            return ""

        params = []
        for arg in args:
            params.append(f"{key}={arg}")

        return "?" + "&".join(params)

    def make_api_request(self, method: str, path: str, body: str = "") -> Any:
        timestamp = self._get_current_timestamp()
        headers = self.get_authorization_header(method, path, body, timestamp)
        url = self.base_url + path

        try:
            response = None
            if method == "GET":
                response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=10)
            elif method == "POST":
                response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=json.loads(body), timeout=10)

            # Print debugging information
            print(f"URL: {url}")
            print(f"Headers: {headers}")
            print(f"Response Status Code: {response.status_code}")
            print(f"Response Text: {response.text}")

            # Check if the response text is empty
            if not response.text:
                print("Received an empty response.")
                return None

            return response.json()
        except requests.RequestException as e:
            print(f"Error making API request: {e}")
            return None

    def get_authorization_header(
            self, method: str, path: str, body: str, timestamp: int
    ) -> Dict[str, str]:
        message_to_sign = f"{self.api_key}{timestamp}{path}{method}{body}"
        signature = self.private_key.sign(message_to_sign.encode("utf-8"))

        return {
            "x-api-key": self.api_key,
            "x-signature": base64.b64encode(signature).decode("utf-8"),
            "x-timestamp": str(timestamp),
        }

    def get_account(self) -> Any:
        path = "/api/v1/crypto/trading/accounts/"
        return self.make_api_request("GET", path)

    # The symbols argument must be formatted in trading pairs, e.g "BTC-USD", "ETH-USD". If no symbols are provided,
    # all supported symbols will be returned
    def get_trading_pairs(self, *symbols: Optional[str]) -> Any:
        query_params = self.get_query_params("symbol", *symbols)
        path = f"/api/v1/crypto/trading/trading_pairs/{query_params}"
        return self.make_api_request("GET", path)

    # The asset_codes argument must be formatted as the short form name for a crypto, e.g "BTC", "ETH". If no asset
    # codes are provided, all crypto holdings will be returned
    def get_holdings(self, *asset_codes: Optional[str]) -> Any:
        query_params = self.get_query_params("asset_code", *asset_codes)
        path = f"/api/v1/crypto/trading/holdings/{query_params}"
        return self.make_api_request("GET", path)

    # The symbols argument must be formatted in trading pairs, e.g "BTC-USD", "ETH-USD". If no symbols are provided,
    # the best bid and ask for all supported symbols will be returned
    def get_best_bid_ask(self, *symbols: Optional[str]) -> Any:
        query_params = self.get_query_params("symbol", *symbols)
        path = f"/api/v1/crypto/marketdata/best_bid_ask/{query_params}"
        return self.make_api_request("GET", path)

    # The symbol argument must be formatted in a trading pair, e.g "BTC-USD", "ETH-USD"
    # The side argument must be "bid", "ask", or "both".
    # Multiple quantities can be specified in the quantity argument, e.g. "0.1,1,1.999".
    def get_estimated_price(self, symbol: str, side: str, quantity: str) -> Any:
        path = f"/api/v1/crypto/marketdata/estimated_price/?symbol={symbol}&side={side}&quantity={quantity}"
        return self.make_api_request("GET", path)

    def place_order(
            self,
            client_order_id: str,
            side: str,
            order_type: str,
            symbol: str,
            order_config: Dict[str, str],
    ) -> Any:
        body = {
            "client_order_id": client_order_id,
            "side": side,
            "type": order_type,
            "symbol": symbol,
            f"{order_type}_order_config": order_config,
        }
        path = "/api/v1/crypto/trading/orders/"
        return self.make_api_request("POST", path, json.dumps(body))

    def cancel_order(self, order_id: str) -> Any:
        path = f"/api/v1/crypto/trading/orders/{order_id}/cancel/"
        response = self.make_api_request("POST", path)
    
        # Additional debugging
        print(f"Cancel Order Response: {response}")
        return response

    def get_order(self, order_id: str) -> Any:
        path = f"/api/v1/crypto/trading/orders/{order_id}/"
        return self.make_api_request("GET", path)

    def get_orders(self) -> Any:
        path = "/api/v1/crypto/trading/orders/"
        return self.make_api_request("GET", path)


def main():

    """
    BUILD YOUR TRADING STRATEGY HERE

    order = api_trading_client.place_order(
          str(uuid.uuid4()),
          "buy",
          "market",
          "BTC-USD",
          {"asset_quantity": "0.0001"}
    )
    """

I'm trying to use the 'cancel_order' function right now. I've made my own function which tries to call the 'cancel_order' function:
def cancel_limit_order():
    most_recent_bot_order = get_most_recent_bot_order()

    if most_recent_bot_order['type'] != 'limit':
        print('The most recent order is not a limit order. Something is wrong')
        return False

    most_recent_bot_order_id = most_recent_bot_order['id']

    try:
        response = api_trading_client.cancel_order(most_recent_bot_order_id)
        print(f'Cancel order response: {response}')

        # Additional debug info
        if response is None:
            print('No response received. Check API request and server status.')
        elif 'error' in response:
            print(f"API Error: {response['error']}")

        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error with cancelling order: {e}')
        response = api_trading_client.cancel_order(most_recent_bot_order_id)
        print(f'Cancel order response: {response}')
        if response is None:
            print('No response received. Check API request and server status.')
        elif 'error' in response:
            print(f"API Error: {response['error']}")
        return False

An error occurs with the 'cancel_order' function when I try to use it. Here's the output I get:
URL: https://trading.robinhood.com/api/v1/crypto/trading/orders/
Headers: {'x-api-key': 'redacted', 'x-signature': 'ecsYkKycTbv1z9C32UuIarzNRGZbOWa/w0V1z7jQkVi4I6xEAaQqTIhX/F6ir4BX0gcAjp05W70n0IPZxOYXAQ==', 'x-timestamp': '1722149992'}
Response Status Code: 200
Response Text: {"next":null,"previous":null,"results":[{"symbol":"BTC-USD","client_order_id":"11111111-c2a8-4c4f-bb6b-ef4c36ee1837","side":"sell","type":"limit","id":"66a5d2fb-9e79-4a3d-8357-09dd7654c6ef","account_number":"311253745830","state":"open","filled_asset_quantity":"0.000000000000000000","executions":[],"average_price":null,"created_at":"2024-07-28T01:11:23.580309-04:00","updated_at":"2024-07-28T01:11:23.963197-04:00","limit_order_config":{"asset_quantity":"0.010000000000000000","limit_price":"100000.000000000000000000"}},{"symbol":"BTC-USD","client_order_id":"11111111-4e75-48c7-a1c0-f3c5fef4c0b6","side":"sell","type":"limit","id":"66a46f8a-3e5e-4c41-adba-b9de5f2e1595","account_number":"311253745830","state":"canceled","filled_asset_quantity":"0.000000000000000000","executions":[],"average_price":null,"created_at":"2024-07-26T23:54:50.627968-04:00","updated_at":"2024-07-28T01:10:32.159892-04:00","limit_order_config":{"asset_quantity":"0.010000000000000000","limit_price":"100000.000000000000000000"}},{"symbol":"AVAX-USD","client_order_id":"11111111-36ea-4143-9723-65f5055ff048","side":"sell","type":"market","id":"66a44751-b5ce-48ae-84a3-97f7e3848d07","account_number":"311253745830","state":"filled","filled_asset_quantity":"0.500000000000000000","executions":[{"effective_price":"28.496000000000000000","quantity":"0.500000000000000000","timestamp":"2024-07-26T21:03:13.812000-04:00"}],"average_price":"28.496000000000000000","created_at":"2024-07-26T21:03:13.614703-04:00","updated_at":"2024-07-26T21:03:14.548993-04:00","market_order_config":{"asset_quantity":"0.500000000000000000"}},{"symbol":"AVAX-USD","client_order_id":"11111111-f191-4cc8-9e7d-9367e07b716b","side":"sell","type":"limit","id":"66a315c2-09de-4ee9-b76f-d50b993693ec","account_number":"311253745830","state":"open","filled_asset_quantity":"0.000000000000000000","executions":[],"average_price":null,"created_at":"2024-07-25T23:19:30.693918-04:00","updated_at":"2024-07-25T23:19:31.181516-04:00","limit_order_config":{"asset_quantity":"21.000000000000000000","limit_price":"40.000000000000000000"}},{"symbol":"BTC-USD","client_order_id":"11111111-0a27-4e10-b1d0-6dbf05ef4d68","side":"buy","type":"market","id":"66a0c0a6-80a5-482a-92bf-8507d89cc1ff","account_number":"311253745830","state":"filled","filled_asset_quantity":"0.000075300000000000","executions":[{"effective_price":"66693.747699810000000000","quantity":"0.000075300000000000","timestamp":"2024-07-24T04:51:50.468000-04:00"}],"average_price":"66693.747699810000000000","created_at":"2024-07-24T04:51:50.139858-04:00","updated_at":"2024-07-24T04:51:51.580646-04:00","market_order_config":{"asset_quantity":"0.000075300000000000"}},{"symbol":"BTC-USD","client_order_id":"2cf90ee7-00b8-4a93-9950-90239bf8bd24","side":"buy","type":"market","id":"669f173f-c734-4895-ba50-b4cc15f991e6","account_number":"311253745830","state":"filled","filled_asset_quantity":"0.000073990000000000","executions":[{"effective_price":"67873.780158900000000000","quantity":"0.000073990000000000","timestamp":"2024-07-22T22:36:47.852000-04:00"}],"average_price":"67873.780158900000000000","created_at":"2024-07-22T22:36:47.378672-04:00","updated_at":"2024-07-22T22:36:48.739653-04:00","market_order_config":{"asset_quantity":"0.000073990000000000"}},{"symbol":"BTC-USD","client_order_id":"554ea01b-642f-4ec2-89bf-c344323be1ac","side":"buy","type":"market","id":"669f0729-a760-45c0-a5a0-3ba6439439f8","account_number":"311253745830","state":"filled","filled_asset_quantity":"0.015963890000000000","executions":[{"effective_price":"67654.319320530000000000","quantity":"0.015963890000000000","timestamp":"2024-07-22T21:28:10.064000-04:00"}],"average_price":"67654.319320530000000000","created_at":"2024-07-22T21:28:09.576433-04:00","updated_at":"2024-07-22T21:28:10.591231-04:00","market_order_config":{"quote_amount":"1080.00"}},{"symbol":"BTC-USD","client_order_id":"4815f9ba-e546-4eb3-b5d5-3b159cbbd0e8","side":"buy","type":"market","id":"669dc87b-f18d-44c1-969c-5116c5a65f00","account_number":"311253745830","state":"filled","filled_asset_quantity":"0.000073290000000000","executions":[{"effective_price":"68520.540000000000000000","quantity":"0.000073290000000000","timestamp":"2024-07-21T22:48:27.694000-04:00"}],"average_price":"68520.540000000000000000","created_at":"2024-07-21T22:48:27.324783-04:00","updated_at":"2024-07-21T22:48:28.105601-04:00","market_order_config":{"asset_quantity":"0.000073290000000000"}},{"symbol":"BTC-USD","client_order_id":"f8273cdc-da2d-4bb8-a547-cedcc246a591","side":"buy","type":"limit","id":"669d9c3b-520f-4063-b15e-042d9ed7eb19","account_number":"311253745830","state":"canceled","filled_asset_quantity":"0.000000000000000000","executions":[],"average_price":null,"created_at":"2024-07-21T19:39:39.085759-04:00","updated_at":"2024-07-21T19:59:22.323724-04:00","limit_order_config":{"quote_amount":"5.00","limit_price":"67990.000000000000000000"}},{"symbol":"AVAX-USD","client_order_id":"3a7bcebc-d381-44f7-89d4-c3a628b5c4dc","side":"sell","type":"market","id":"669b448c-5ca3-4b21-9d90-02fbeef48483","account_number":"311253745830","state":"filled","filled_asset_quantity":"0.705700000000000000","executions":[{"effective_price":"28.352910000000000000","quantity":"0.705700000000000000","timestamp":"2024-07-20T01:01:00.767000-04:00"}],"average_price":"28.352910000000000000","created_at":"2024-07-20T01:01:00.605289-04:00","updated_at":"2024-07-20T01:01:01.115093-04:00","market_order_config":{"quote_amount":"20.00"}},{"symbol":"AVAX-USD","client_order_id":"7fd2f86d-1efe-4f63-b348-309da07b7170","side":"buy","type":"market","id":"668eba89-d97c-4253-be57-99f928c20eda","account_number":"311253745830","state":"filled","filled_asset_quantity":"3.500000000000000000","executions":[{"effective_price":"26.508849370000000000","quantity":"3.500000000000000000","timestamp":"2024-07-10T12:44:58.149000-04:00"}],"average_price":"26.508849370000000000","created_at":"2024-07-10T12:44:57.826274-04:00","updated_at":"2024-07-10T12:44:59.080134-04:00","market_order_config":{"asset_quantity":"3.500000000000000000"}},{"symbol":"AVAX-USD","client_order_id":"0a55733d-af78-4122-bd3f-b6a65e3e8bb0","side":"sell","type":"limit","id":"6678cdd2-3b6c-44f1-854d-be7389b678fb","account_number":"311253745830","state":"canceled","filled_asset_quantity":"0.000000000000000000","executions":[],"average_price":null,"created_at":"2024-06-23T21:37:22.439164-04:00","updated_at":"2024-07-25T23:15:23.210202-04:00","limit_order_config":{"asset_quantity":"18.982500000000000000","limit_price":"60.000000000000000000"}},{"symbol":"AVAX-USD","client_order_id":"d2be1fba-a0cc-4029-9b19-0d14de366182","side":"buy","type":"market","id":"66779c82-f714-4628-8e20-a2d3f0d03421","account_number":"311253745830","state":"filled","filled_asset_quantity":"18.982500000000000000","executions":[{"effective_price":"26.083000000000000000","quantity":"18.982500000000000000","timestamp":"2024-06-22T23:54:43.117000-04:00"}],"average_price":"26.083000000000000000","created_at":"2024-06-22T23:54:42.804401-04:00","updated_at":"2024-06-22T23:54:43.612939-04:00","market_order_config":{"quote_amount":"500.00"}}]}
Latest order: {'symbol': 'BTC-USD', 'client_order_id': '11111111-c2a8-4c4f-bb6b-ef4c36ee1837', 'side': 'sell', 'type': 'limit', 'id': '66a5d2fb-9e79-4a3d-8357-09dd7654c6ef', 'account_number': '311253745830', 'state': 'open', 'filled_asset_quantity': '0.000000000000000000', 'executions': [], 'average_price': None, 'created_at': '2024-07-28T01:11:23.580309-04:00', 'updated_at': '2024-07-28T01:11:23.963197-04:00', 'limit_order_config': {'asset_quantity': '0.010000000000000000', 'limit_price': '100000.000000000000000000'}}
Error with cancelling order: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/andrestendahl/Desktop/mlProjects/Finance/Crypto_MK3_Robinhood/helper_functions.py", line 384, in <module>
    cancel_limit_order()
  File "/Users/andrestendahl/Desktop/mlProjects/Finance/Crypto_MK3_Robinhood/helper_functions.py", line 190, in cancel_limit_order
    response = api_trading_client.cancel_order(most_recent_bot_order_id)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/andrestendahl/Desktop/mlProjects/Finance/Crypto_MK3_Robinhood/robinhood_api_trading.py", line 121, in cancel_order
    response = self.make_api_request("POST", path)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/andrestendahl/Desktop/mlProjects/Finance/Crypto_MK3_Robinhood/robinhood_api_trading.py", line 45, in make_api_request
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=json.loads(body), timeout=10)
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/andrestendahl/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/andrestendahl/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/andrestendahl/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

It seems like the '200' response means the 'GET' method was successful, but that something went wrong with the 'POST' method. I've been trying to debug further with various print statements but I haven't made any progress. I'm also not sure what the error message 'Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)' actually means.
Here are the docs I've been using:
https://docs.robinhood.com/crypto/trading/#tag/Trading/operation/api_v1_post_crypto_trading_cancel_order
Let me know if there's any more info I should provide.

Where's the output of the POST? Response Text is missing from the output, but cancelling an order doesn't return json,

@OneCricketeer added in the response text.

You're not passing a body parameter in the POST request, so json=json.loads(body) gets an empty string when it is "Expecting a value". You could try putting body={} as the default parameter, otherwise you'll need a conditional check on the POST request not to send an empty body. You also don't need json.dumps(), since requests does that for you when provided a dictionary
Also, according to the docs, the cancel API also does not return JSON response, so return response.json() may not work and you'll need to handle that as well

Ah okay I added in "{}" as the third parameter (the 'body' parameter) in the call to 'make_api_request' in the 'cancel_order' function and it works now. Thanks
